# make install: pkg-config does not find installed library

Tags: installation, qt5, cross-compiling, dbus, pkg-config

I cross-compiled successfully an application from sources (Qt5 on Debian). When I type `make install` it returns this error:

> Updating projects from gyp files...
>   Package dbus-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `dbus-1.pc'
>   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'dbus-1' found

But:

```
pkg-config --modversion dbus-1
1.10.8
pkg-config --libs dbus-1
-ldbus-1
```

So it actually finds the `dbus-1` library.
Furthermore:

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/home/mark/opt/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig/:/home/mark/opt/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig
```

shows the package is on the sysroot side (target architecture).
What does this error really mean?

Comment: Well, `pkg-config --debug dbus-1` reveals: Package dbus-1 has -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu in Libs. So it searches before in the host path, instead of in `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

Comment: Are you trying to cross-compile the Qt library or a Qt-based program?

Comment: The Qt library. Anyway rebooting the host machine and retype the same commands fixed the issue. Perhaps something was messed up...

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663067/pkg-config-cant-find-libraries-on-ffmpeg-build-linux