# pkg-config cant find libraries on ffmpeg build (linux)

Tags: android, linux, ffmpeg, cross-compiling, pkg-config

I'm trying to build ffmpeg for android on ubuntu...

```
-I've cross-compiled all the dependencies I need for my configuration
-I've set up the configuration parameters
```

but ./configure keep saying

```
ERROR: librtmp not found using pkg-config
```

I've tested and if I remove `--enable-librtmp` it will configure complain about other library. The thing is I i build all libs myself. So I'm sure it is present and at right folder.

I'm not linux/compiler specialist and so far i've spend more than 10 days to get everything i need to this project rightly done. I know i can simple modify the configure file under ffmpeg and remove the pkg-config check but this isn't the solution I'm looking for

the command i run is:

```
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --arch=${ARCH}\
    --cpu=${CPU} \
    --cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --target-os=linux \
    --sysinclude=$NDK/sysroot/usr/include \
    --pkg-config=$(which pkg-config) \
    --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
    --enable-pic \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-nonfree \
    \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    \
    --enable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    \
    --enable-librtmp \
    --enable-zlib \
    --enable-mediacodec \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-libfdk-aac\
    --enable-libfreetype\
    --enable-libmp3lame\
    --enable-openssl\
    --enable-libfontconfig\
    --enable-bsf=aac_adtstoasc \
    \
    --disable-doc \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
```

I would like to know which tests pkg-config do to detect if any lib is installed? and how can i show it the libs i need are really present

=========UPDATE=========

`${PREFIX}` stands for `build_dir` under which i've a folder `lib/pkgconfig` with many .pc files including `librtmp.pc`. so why it can detect the others but not this one? i checked the content of the file and seams to be right, similar to others at same folder

Comment: Check config.log file :)

Answer (score 4):

try this command before do ./configure

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I met similar problem when I installed libx265.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm new to these things and it was helpful